# How to override the Windows tree command?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, tree

```sh
C:\Users\client>npm install -g tree-cli
+ tree-cli@0.6.4
updated 1 package in 2.374s



C:\Users\client>tree --help
卷 Windows-SSD 的文件夹 PATH 列表
卷序列号为 B20D-EC93
C:\USERS\CLIENT\--HELP
无效的路径 - \USERS\CLIENT\--HELP
```

I installed tree-cli. https://github.com/MrRaindrop/tree-cli

But this command is occupied by windows.

I want to use the tree of tree-cli, not the tree of windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the command `treee`. See the note in the README [here](https://github.com/MrRaindrop/tree-cli#for-windows-users).

Comment: Well, thank you very much, I just found this in `tree-cli->package.json`